# flash as3 movieclip.stop(); does not work in my case

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

My issue: Imported a swf file through content loader. It has two frames, and I want to stop it at frame 1. Its basically an animated start button which will animate on mouse_over.
start_button.stop(); does not work. It just plays continuously. I cannot use button from library as it is a university assignment where everything has to be loaded in externally.

Appreciate all help.

```
    function Main()
    {
        start_button_ldr.load(new URLRequest("images/start_button.swf"));
        start_button_ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showMainMenu);
    }

    function showMainMenu($evt:Event):void
    {
        start_button = MovieClip(start_button_ldr.content);
        start_button.x = SCENE_WIDTH / 2;
        start_button.y = SCENE_HEIGHT / 2;
        start_button.buttonMode = true;
        start_button.useHandCursor = true;
        start_button.stop();
        start_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startGame);
        this.addChild(start_button);

        start_button_ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, showMainMenu);
    }
```

Comment: Or if anyone else have suggestions to how I can get an animated button loaded in externally, I would happily accept :)

Comment: Is this an iOS project, by any chance? Loaded SWFs will play on those, but executable code within them will be ignored, because Apple doesn't allow any executable code to be loaded at runtime.

Comment: No, its just an assignment to be used on a computer / web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer to the question, but Flash has build in what you are creating: You should use a **runtime shared library**.

Go to symbol properties of your button in the library. choose '`Export for runtime sharing`'. Make sure the url is `start_button.swf`. Then drag the button in the .fla where it should be used. In the library you 'import:' in the linkage column and the '`Import for runtime sharing`' in the symbol properties is checked. Run the file.

With a http debugger you'll see it automatically loads the .swf. This works very pretty and gives nice way to work with external stuff, since it acts like its local.

Comment: start_button is just a movieClip that I make into a button. Im not allowed to have anything in the library nor on the stage in the .fla, which, if I understood correctly, is what you are explaining me to do.
I need to find a way to have an animated movieClip / button to load it 100% externally.